# DateTimeFormField is not updating after setState call (need more than just giving initialValue? I don't know how to use a controller here)

Tags: flutter

I have a problem of refreshing my DateTimeFormField after a setState call, do someone having the same problem or I am just missing the right code?

I am using:

```
date_field: ^3.0.0
```

Here is my code:

```
DateTimeFormField(
    initialValue: myInitialValue,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.event_note),
        labelText: 'Time line',
     ),
     mode: DateTimeFieldPickerMode.date,
     onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
       myInitialValue = value;
     },
),
```

Then hope to see the date changing after a:

```
setState(() { myInitialValue = value; });
```

I was hoping to have something like a controller here but can't find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield
   follow URL document
   or
2. setState(() { myInitialValue = value; });

Then hope to see the date change

use any above option

Comment: Thank you @ionicfirebaseapp for your quick response. You suggest to replace date_field by datetime_picker_formfield in the first option? I am actually doing the second option but it's not working. Thanks.